# Getting following error on migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, rails-migrations

I am working on rails 2 project and am getting the following error while running rake tasks. Can someone help me out as what may be causing this.

```
[root@localhost webapp]# rake db:migrate
(in /root/public/webapp)
==  CreateWhereKeywords: migrating ============================================
-- create_table(:where_keywords)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "where_keywords_id_seq" for serial column "where_keywords.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "where_keywords_pkey" for table "where_keywords"
   -> 0.0838s
-- execute("alter table where_keywords add constraint where_keyword foreign key (where_location_id) references \n        where_locations(id) on delete cascade")
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  foreign key constraint "where_keyword" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "where_location_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and integer.
: alter table where_keywords add constraint where_keyword foreign key (where_location_id) references 
        where_locations(id) on delete cascade
```

Comment: Show us the code in your migration, and the schema of all tables involved.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is fairly clear:

> Key columns "where_location_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: character varying and integer

You're creating the `where_keywords.where_location_id` column as a `varchar` when it needs to be an `integer` so that it can refer to `where_locations.id` in the FK. Your migration has something like this:

```
create_table :where_keywords do |t|
  #...
  t.string :where_location_id
  #...
end
```

that should be more like this:

```
create_table :where_keywords do |t|
  #...
  t.integer :where_location_id
  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. I am a newbie ,really appreciate your guidance